# 'apply' on two different data frames at once in R

Tags: r

I am wondering whether there is a way to use apply-family function to evaluate two different dataframes at once? Or is there a better way to solve this problem? I can only think of a loop, and that is too slow:

```
# example data
df_model <- data.frame(DY = c(93,100,107), CC=rnorm(1:3, mean = 0.1))

df_data  <- data.frame(DY = rep(c(93,100,107),each = 3), CC = c(rnorm(1:3),rnorm(1:3),rnorm(1:3)))
```

In this example, I would like to have a vector of three elements as output, processed as follows ( here for the first case)

```
#example procedure case 1
collect <- matrix(0,ncol=3,nrow=3)
 collect[1,] <-  dnorm( df_data[which(df_data$DY == df_model$DY[1]),]$CC, df_model[1,]$CC, log=TRUE )
```

as Input, I envisage
a list/vector of CCs in df_data, subsetted for by the corresponding day DY  (0.07624536 1.32623789 0.92921693)
evaluated against one value (0.00049671) of df_model, on that corresponding day DY

In the end I would like to collect the vectors in example(collect) a matrix of the number of rows of three df_model$DY, and three columns, which contains the evaluation of df_data against df_model on day DY.

```
       [,1]     [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.9218075 -1.7977334 -1.3501992
[2,] -0.9356356 -0.9850012 -1.1753341
[3,] -1.2152926 -0.9195071 -2.4127840
```

This needs to be done as efficiently as possible.
I can do it in a loop (above you see the first case for the loop), but I am sure there are better ways.
I looked into the apply function family, but I get confused, as I have two different dataframes which I evaluate. Any help/pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mapply` or `Map`

```
mapply(function(x, y) dnorm(df_data$CC[df_data$DY == x], y, 
       log = TRUE), df_model$DY, df_model$CC)
```

-output

```
#          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] -1.5031401 -2.7449464 -1.734319
#[2,] -0.9237629 -0.9243094 -1.115875
#[3,] -4.9848319 -1.1494313 -1.187122
```

Comment: Thank-you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for!!